# she said vexing OR she vexed

Tags: word-choice

Can I use "vexed" in the example: "You're impossible!" she vexed.

or would I have to write: "You're impossible!" she said vexing.

Any thoughts much appreciated,
thanks and have a lovely day :)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to convey by *vex*? Have you checked a good dictionary for the meaning and usage of *vex* and its various forms?

Answer (score 2):

The transitive is the normal application:

> [Rosamunda's Revenge](https://books.google.ca/books?id=d_n-9noa8tsC&q=%22said%20vexing%22&dq=%22said%20vexing%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=zNsXVcTlFOH9sATspYLAAg&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAzgU) - Page 34 Emma Craig - 1997
>
> "No, no, dear," Tacita **said, vexing her**.

where Tacita irritates/vexes the other woman.

Now, the intransitive branch also exists:

> **vex**
>
> intransitive verb
>
> :  to suffer distress (as of mind) :  **become irritated :  fret,
>   worry**
>
> Merriam-Webster Unabridged Dictionary

thus this would be possible:

*"You're impossible!" she **said, vexing**.*

where

vexing = becoming irritated

is used here as an adverbial of manner. Comma is mandatory, for this is non-restrictive.

BTW, you'll find the verb these days only in Romance novels :-)

"To vex" has been used as an intransitive verb, but the examples I found are quite old:

> [Diary of Samuel Pepys - Complete](https://books.google.ca/books?id=YZ59AwAAQBAJ&pg=PT419&dq=%22%20vexing%20about%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=bAQYVbHKLOPZsATW3YD4CA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22%20vexing%20about%22&f=false) Samuel Pepys
>
> All this morning **at home vexing about the delay** of my painters,
>   and about four in the afternoon my wife and I by water to Captain
>   Lambert's, where we took great pleasure in their turret garden, and
>   seeing the fine needleworks of his wife

where
vexing = worrying, becoming irritated (as in the M-W U Dictionary above)

Being so rare, you may want to listen to the advice given in the comments by  Brian Hitchcock and avoid using it.

BTW, I've just checked with two BrE native speakers, and they've told me Pepys' intransitive usage isn't heard any more over there.

Comment: Not a good idea to use vex in either of those ways. The adjective "vexed" applied to a person, and the adjective "vexing" describing a problem, are the only forms still heard (in AmE). Never heard it used as a verb. You could write it, but not if you wish to be understood.

Comment: @Brian Hitchcock You may well be right. I found examples as a verb (see Pepys in the answer) but they are rare, and I never heard it used this way.

Comment: @Brian: I think it's still in use (although rare) as a transitive verb. But I don't think I have ever heard it as an intransitive verb, as in *"she said, vexing"*; it would be much better to use *"she said, getting vexed"*.

Answer (score 0):

***Vexed or Vexing*** can be used as adjectives.

The meaning of **Vexed** is  ***irritated, distressed, or annoyed, or confused or agitated, or much debated and discussed*** *(especially in the phrase a **vexed question**)*. E.g. - *The vexed parents of a drug addict teenager...; At last she raised the vexed question.*

The meaning of **vexing** is ***extremely annoying or displeasing, or causing irritation or annoyance.*** E.g. - *The noise of the engine is very vexing. I have had a vexing day.*

So a **better** construction would be -

a. ***"You're impossible!" she said in a vexed manner/attitude/mood.***

b.  ***"You're impossible!" she said in a vexing tone/mood.***

P.S. - But I think the construction - " "You're impossible!" she vexed" - may also be correct. Being not a native speaker I regret that I am not 100% sure.

Comment: I hope you realize that (a) and (b) mean quite different things.